# persmissions of .svn/entries

Tags: svn, permissions

My application runs under tomcat7 and stores files on the local file system. These files eventually get committed to SVN. When they are committed, the contents of the .svn directory looks like this:

```
drwxr-xr-x 6 tomcat7 tomcat7 4.0K 2012-07-05 22:12 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 tomcat7 tomcat7 4.0K 2012-06-16 18:14 ..
-r--r--r-- 1 tomcat7 tomcat7  265 2012-06-16 18:23 all-wcprops
-r--r--r-- 1 root    root     558 2012-06-30 13:53 entries
drwxr-xr-x 2 tomcat7 tomcat7 4.0K 2012-06-16 18:23 prop-base
drwxr-xr-x 2 tomcat7 tomcat7 4.0K 2012-06-16 18:23 props
drwxr-xr-x 2 tomcat7 tomcat7 4.0K 2012-06-16 18:23 text-base
drwxr-xr-x 5 tomcat7 tomcat7 4.0K 2012-06-30 13:53 tmp
```

Notice that the `entries` directory is owned by root/root, whereas all others are owned by tomcat7/tomcat7. This is currently preventing the application (which runs as the tomcat7 user) from deleting any of the directories containing files committed to SVN.

Is there some way that I can configure the .svn/entries file to be owned by tomcat7/tomcat7, like all the other files under .svn?

Comment: When you say "These files eventually get committed to SVN", what's doing the committing?

Comment: a shell script that performs a daily backup

Comment: So, why not have the shell script run under the `tomcat7` account?

Answer (score 0):

I don't it's task of svn to deal with file permissions.

Maybe you can just recursively `chown` all files under working copy to tomcat7:tomcat7.

Comment: this will only fix the problem for existing directories, it won't help for new directories that are created

Comment: @Don Why some files/directories are created as tomcat7:tomcat7, while other as root:root? Is there running something else besides tomcat, that creates files/directories belonging to root?

Comment: that's essentially the question I've asked (in other words, I don't know)

Answer (score 0):

```
chown tomcat7:tomcat7 entries
```

This is a late answer but I just came across this from a search.